# How does "daw" to delete a word in Vim work if "dw" only deletes part of the word?

Tags: vim

I'm a Vim user and I want to delete a keyword. I always use "dw" to delete a specific keyword, but it sometimes doesn't work well. For example, I want to delete "valule123" in sample program.

```
ex) public void function(int valule123)
```

When I put my cursor is on "2", and then I input "dw", only part of keyword is deleted and the result is "valule1". Why?

I tried another command, "daw". In this case, the result is just as expected! But what does "a" mean? I think "a" means "add".

Comment: See `:help text-objects`

Answer (score 39):

The command/action/verb `d` in Vim acts on an object. For `dw` the object is "all text the cursor moves over with a `w` command". For `daw` you're actually using a Vim concept called a "text object". There are many of these, including `aw` (a word), `as` (a sentence), `i}` (inner {...} block, e.g. code within a block in C code), `it` (inner tag, useful for XML-like languages), and more.

See `:help text-objects` for the full list.

These can not only be used by the `d` command, but any command/action/verb that takes an object. For example, `=aB` will reindent an entire code block, `cas` will delete a sentence and drop you into insert mode to type a new one, and `yit` will yank/copy everything inside the current XML tag.

Answer (score 18):

dw: deletes word from the cursor to the end of the word. 
daw: deletes the word under the cursor. 
There is also the option of writing caw, this one does the same as daw, but also puts you into insert mode.

Answer (score 12):

If you type `:help daw` inside Vim console, you will see it means "delete a word". So, 'a' means *a* here. More from the doc:

> For example, compare "dw" and "daw": "dw" deletes from the cursor
>   position to the start of the next word, "daw" deletes the word under
>   the cursor and the space after or before it.

If you don't want to delete the space after/before it, you can use `diw` (*delete inner word*).

Answer (score 6):

For these cases, you can always use: `diw` that way it won't matter where your cursor is over the word it will always remove the entire word.

- `d`: delete
- `i`: internal/inner
- `w`: word

Another useful use is `ciw` (*change internal word*) to delete the word and go into insert mode.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In case that I know the word to delete, my flow of deleting would be:

1. Find `:/deleting-word` and cursor at the end of the deleting word.
2. on `-- INSERT --`, combo [**ctrl** + **w**] to delete that word, or keep going for multiple words.

Comment: Easier is dgn after the search

Answer (score 0):

- `lbce` may work well if you want to change a word in a english sentence despite where the cursor position in the word you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

When navigating around `dw` will delete a word. Of course `w` will navigate from the first character of a word to the next word, whilst `b` the previous word etc.

Given that you use the navigation keys `j,k,h,l` (down, up, left, right ), if you're in a word on a particular charachter, you can type `d` for delete then `l` and the character to the right will be deleted, or `h` and the character to the left will. It's more intuitve when your fingers are actually on the keys