# Deleting a word, starting at the end of the word, leaves the last character of the word

Tags: vim

I have the following problem in Vim.
When I want to delete with `db` the last character doesn't get removed.

```
foo bar some words cool
                      ^ Cursor is here, now call 'db'

foo bar some words l   <- result, l not deleted
```

But I also want to delete the 'l' from 'cool'.
I could use `bdw` do achieve my goal, but this feels counter intuitive.
Are there better ways do achieve my goal?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885064/how-to-delete-a-word-in-vim#18885234

Comment: No, neither of those are duplicates or answer the question.

Comment: @romainl do you mean that multiple answers to the first linked question which suggest to use `diw` do not answer this question?

Comment: The stated problem is different. We close questions because the questions themselves are duplicates, not because their answers overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to operate on the whole current word is to use the `:help iw` text object, *from anywhere in the word*:

```
diw
```

But, if you enjoy the cognitive weight of worrying about where the cursor is and where you want it to be, you can force `:help b` to *include* the current character by injecting a `v` between `d` and `b`:

```
dvb
```

or, simply, use visual selection directly:

```
vbd
```

`db` doesn't do what you want it to do because the motion is *exclusive*. From `:help exclusive`:

```
A character motion is either inclusive or exclusive.  When inclusive, the
start and end position of the motion are included in the operation.  When
exclusive, the last character towards the end of the buffer is not included.
Linewise motions always include the start and end position.
```

That `v`, between the operator and the motion, is a way to force the motion to be *inclusive*. See `:help forced-motion`.